# Change behavior of "Add new Android Components" on Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I am having a problem with my build.gradle file every time that I insert a new Fragment from AndroidStudio. When I use the tool that AndroidStudio provides to insert a new component such as fragments or activities, it creates the fragment class .java and the associated  layout, but it also modifies my build.gradle, for example, my dependencies are reordered but the build.gradle file is broken after that because the order is not done properly. I attach an image with the example.

Why is it behavior happening and how could I prevent it?

I am using AndroidStudio v2.1.1 stable channel

[image: build.gradle file result example]